# How to get the JSON Response so I can alert() for debugging

Tags: javascript, json, fullcalendar

I need to JSON response string/object for debugging purposes. How can i get it?

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(object));
```

That's everything I can give you, as you don't even provide a code example...

Comment: <script type='text/javascript'>
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
     editable: true,
     events: "<?php echo $this->baseUrl(); ?>/entities/appointments/list/",
     eventDrop: function(event, delta) {
      alert(event.title + ' was moved ' + delta + ' days\n' +
       '(should probably update your database)');
     },
     loading: function(bool) {
      if (bool) $('#loading').show();
      else $('#loading').hide();
     }
    });
   });
  </script>

Comment: What's with that? That is not JSON.

Answer (score 0):

for this json:

```
[
    {                   
        "id": "1",
        "title": "All Day Event ", 
        "allDay": true,
        "start": "1283378679",
        "end": null,
        "url": "#",
        "className": "event-type-one",
        "editable": "true",
        "source": null,
        "description": "Sed enim et mauris purus nisi auctor, amet integer rhoncus, dapibus augue scelerisque."
    }
```

]

response string would be

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      events: "( your path to json )/events.json"
      alert(event.id);
      alert(event.title);
      alert(event.allDay); 
});
```

etc.